# How to delete circle in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

A few days ago I updated the android studio and now in layouts is a circle, how to remove them and change image ?

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54nfV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open activity_main.xml and add `android:visibility="gone"` to

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin">
```

Answer (score 4):

This is Floating Action button (android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton) and you can find it in your Layout xml file.

To remove it from xml file. That easy. Just delete this part:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

To change image, change drawable source like that:

```
 android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
```